# How to make <Text /> as watermark of images in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, styles, react-native

To make `<Text />` as watermark of images, it shows in official Docs:

> Background Image via Nesting
>
> > A common feature request from developers familiar with the web is background-image. To handle this use case, simply create a normal `<Image>` component and add whatever children to it you would like to layer on top of it.

```
return (
    <Image source={...}>
        <Text>Inside</Text>
    </Image>
);
```

I tried, the "Inside" has white background, not the part of the image.

How to make "Inside" as a watermark of the image? Thanks.

Comment: Try `style={{background: 'transparent'}}` on the `Text` element

Comment: @jevakallio It is still having a white background

Comment: @jevakallio {{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}

Comment: oops, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageBackground component

Link-> https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

```
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const image = { uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" };

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 42,
    lineHeight: 84,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000000c0"
  }
});

export default App;
```